# Token Factory total supply is missing

Tags: tokens

So I created a token using Token Factory.  I hadn't used it before and wanted to test things out, so I did this on the Ropsten Test Net.

I was able to successfully publish the contract, which shows up Meta Mask History.

Now when I go back to Token Factory and reference the address to interact with it, I am told "Total Supply is: . "

What happened to my Token?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this. More than likely the OP simply forgot to switch back to Ropstein. The token symbol and logo seems to show up on  mainnet(at least on metamask) but values appear to come through as null on the code.